# how can i combine 3 List of different object into one new object with Java 8

Tags: java

I have 3 objects List and i would like to combine it base on they unique key into one object List.

Since **Loan** depend on **Account** and **Account** depend on **Bank**
is there simple way without multiple looping for each object in java 8?

I know its better to do it in single query but wonder if there is something existing with Java 8 using **List** and combine it into one list.

```
public class Bank {

    private String institution; //pk
    private String transit; //pk
    private String bankName;

}

public class Account {

    private String institution; //pk
    private String transit; //pk
    private String accountNo; //pk
    private String nameAccount;

}

public class Loan {

    private String institution;//pk
    private String transit;//pk
    private String accountNo;//pk
    private String serviceNo;//pk

}


// fusion object
public class CombineObject {

    private String institution;
    private String transit;
    private String accountNo;
    private String serviceNo;
    private String nameAccount;
    private String bankName;

}

List<Bank> lstBank = myListBank();
List<Account> lstAccount = myListAccount();
List<Loan> lstLoan = myListLoan();
```

Comment: which field is the unique key?

Comment: institution and transit on those 3 object. But Account has accountNo that Loan has.

Comment: Oh my! Why do you have 4 different fields in your primary key? Use auto-generated, purely technical identifiers. Everything will be much easier, and more efficient, too.

Comment: that only few field of the object it far more greater than that i just show the pk on each object

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that using functional fields for the PK is a terrible idea, and that 4 fields for a PK is 3 fields too much.

Comment: ask the guy that did that before i even born i just replicate the situation i am in but still looking for a idea how combine those list object. If i could refactor everything i would.

Comment: Transform each list into a map, where the key of the map is the composite PK of the object. Then iterate through the loans, and extract the corresponding account from the account map, and the corresponding bank from the bank map.

Comment: Do you want the result like an INNER JOIN or an OUTER JOIN *(using SQL phrases)*? --- An *inner join* is looping over the Loans, filling in `nameAccount` and `bankName`. Banks and/or Accounts with no Loans will not be in the result. --- An *outer* join will include banks and/or accounts without Loans, leaving the Loan fields null.